# Add server node to existing k3s cluster using kubevip

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a k3s cluster consiting of one server node and three worker nodes, currently running.  I would like to add a new server node to ensure HA if the server nodes goes down.  I am using ksup and kubevip.  I already added the vip to the primary node and it is now pingable, when I attempt to run the script below it fails.  When I log into the failed node and look at the logs I see this error:

```
domain='domain.local'
hostname='k3s-master02'
master='k3s-cluster01'
k3sup join --host "$hostname"."$domain" \
--server --server-host "$master"."$domain" \
--user my_user --k3s-channel stable \
--k3s-extra-args '--disable servicelb --disable traefik'
```

```
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.domain.local sh[18740]: + /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.zbs.local systemctl[18741]: Failed to get unit file state for nm-cloud-setup.service: No such file or directory
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.domain.local k3s[18744]: time="2023-12-23T13:22:57-05:00" level=info msg="Starting k3s v1.28.4+k3s2 (6ba6c1b6)"
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.domain.local k3s[18744]: time="2023-12-23T13:22:57-05:00" level=fatal msg="starting kubernetes: preparing server: CA cert validation failed: Get \"https://k3s-cluster01.domain.>
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.domain.local systemd[1]: k3s.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.domain.local systemd[1]: k3s.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 23 13:22:57 k3s-master02.domain.local systemd[1]: Failed to start k3s.service - Lightweight Kubernetes.
```